# Title on custom UINavigationItem is not shown

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uinavigationitem

I'm creating custom UINavigationItem with custom background image and title. The image is shown but the title doesn't. What could be wrong? 
I'm doing it this way:

```
UIButton *button =  [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom]; 
[button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bar_button.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal]; 
[button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bar_button_black.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
[button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bar_button_black.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
[button setTitle:@"Cancel" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button setTitle:@"Cancel" forState:UIControlStateSelected];
[button setTitle:@"Cancel" forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(closeButtonClicked) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside]; 

[button setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 49, 30)]; 
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:button];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set image as backgroundImage not direct. If you set image like this

```
[button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bar_button.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

the title will not be displayed

set like this

```
[button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bar_button.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you must remove:

```
[button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bar_button.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

After that, the title will appear

Answer (score 0):

Either remove this line

```
[button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bar_button.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

or you can change the Title color to some other color.i hope it will solve your problem.

make it to DrakgrayColor or some other color which can overcome your image color.

Comment: Presumably removing the image is not an option as then the button would look wrong. Changing the title colour would be better.

Answer (score 0):

OK. Found a workaround, however I'm not sure whether it is allowed:

```
UIBarButtonItem *closeButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Close",@"Close") style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(closeButtonClicked)];
[self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:closeButton];

for (UIView *view in self.navigationController.navigationBar.subviews) {        
    if ([[[view class] description] isEqualToString:@"UINavigationButton"]) {
        UINavigationButton *button = {(UINavigationButton *)view};
        [button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bar_button.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bar_button_black.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
        [button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bar_button_black.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];

    }
}
```

Comment: UINavigationButton is a private sub class of UINavigationBar and it isn't accessible.